# How do I fix a "Vue packages version mismatch" error on Laravel Spark v4.0.9?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-spark

When I run `npm run dev` on a Laravel Spark v4.0.9 app, I get the following error:

```
Module build failed: Error:

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.0.8
- vue-template-compiler@2.2.6

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.
```

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "js-cookie": "^2.1.0",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "moment": "^2.10.6",
    "promise": "^7.1.1",
    "sweetalert": "^1.1.3",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "urijs": "^1.17.0",
    "vue": "~2.0.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.2.0",
    "vue-router": "^2.2.1",
    "vue-truncate-filter": "^1.1.6",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^0.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.4"
  }
}
```

I have tried the following (at different times, not in order):

- deleted `node_modules` and `npm install`
- tried just running `yarn` and `yarn upgrade`
- removing `vue-loader` and reinstalling
- specifying exact versions of vue and vue-template-compiler rather than leaving it up to npm to install or yarn to figure out dependencies
- removing other non-essential packages (vue-router, vue-truncate-filter, vuejs-datepicker) and trying all of the above again
- banging my head against a wall

Comment: `yarn upgrade vue` up to 2.4.1 fixed this issue for me

Comment: A solution for Vue 3 would be nice :|

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Modify `package.json`:

   ```
   “vue”: “^2.0.8",
   “vue-template-compiler”: “^2.1.8"
   ```
2. Delete `node_modules`
3. Run `npm install`

Comment: Like a boss! Yea, that worked for me too. Thanks @Espen.

Comment: I am having this issue. Tried everythin explained but did not work. getting the same error

Comment: I think don't need to delete node_modules, I faced it and just install the template, npm install that's all

Comment: Per an answer below as an alternative, you can `yarn upgrade vue@^2.0.8` and 
`yarn upgrade vue-template-compiler@^2.1.8`

Comment: A life saver, nothing less.

Answer (score 29):

For vue `^2.5.17`.

In your `package.json`

Simply Add this in `devDependencies` or update the version of `vue-template-compiler`:

- `"vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"`

You wil have this output:

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "lodash": "^4.17.4",
  "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
  "vue": "^2.5.17", // <= note the version
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17" // <= note the version
},
```

After that, run:

```
npm install
```

Npm will update only the updated packages.

Comment: Do you know why it suddenly broke? I never updated my npm, but suddenly it stopped working. Thanks

Answer (score 24):

Don't need to remove all `node_modules` folder. Just update packages: `vue`, `vue-template-compiler` and `vue-server-renderer` by `@latest` flag and it should help for any cases with dismatched versions of vue packages.

`npm i vue-template-compiler@latest --save`

`npm i vue-server-renderer@latest --save`

`--save` will automatically update version in your `package.json` file. `@latest` means install latest available version of package. If you need to update `vue` do it by the same way like we do it in above example.

Also, you always can check new versions for updates by command: `npm outdated`. It shows you all list of packages, that should be updated.

By the way, `npm update` command update only **minor** and **patches** versions, but it unusles when you want to update **major** version. For example `npm update` will not update `2.4.5` => `3.0.1`, but can update

Comment: .. `2.4.5` => `2.6.3` (for example)

Answer (score 16):

Running the following command helped me

`npm install vue-template-compiler@2.5.16 --save-dev`

NB. Replace the version number with the right version that you need. In my case the version of vue was **2.5.16 and vue-template-compiler was 2.5.13** hence I updated the vue-template-compiler to the version of the vue.

Hope this helps someone

[Vue packages version mismatch error fix](https://anansewaa.com/vue-packages-version-mismatch-error-fix/)

Comment: Fixed it for me :)

Comment: Worked for me too, my vue version was 2.5.13 and vue-template-compiler was 2.5.17 but after running the command, it compiled properly. Thanks

Comment: Am glad it did @nensamuel

Answer (score 10):

This steps helped me:

```
rm package-lock.json, rm -rf node_modules, npm update, npm install
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks! 
By the way, I've experienced this on Laravel Nova.

Answer (score 8):

Check dependency for `vue` and replace with exact in dev dependency for `vue-template-compiler`.

For eg.

```
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
},
"devDependencies": {
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.3",
},
```

Should be replaced with:

```
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "2.5.2",
},
"devDependencies": {
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.5.2",
},
```

And run the `npm install` again.

Comment: This was the solution for me. Same versions for both vue and vue-template-compiler and without the leading ^

Comment: @Juljan thanks for reminding me about the leading ^

Answer (score 8):

Updating Vue was the solution for me.

```
npm i vue@latest --save
```

Want to mention that previously I do the steps described in [Kamil' Ocean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52971917/6531256) answer:

```
npm i vue-template-compiler@latest --save

npm i vue-server-renderer@latest --save
```

Once updated Vue it worked.

Comment: The best answer here.

Answer (score 8):

I run the following command:
`yarn global upgrade`

That will upgrade any relation that need some upgrading

Answer (score 6):

Here, vue template compiler compiles the vue template. If you use vue one version and vue-template-compiler another version, that's a problem.

**Run this command**

```
npm update vue-template-compiler
```

This will fix the issue and it will install a vue template compiler same version like vue js version.

Answer (score 6):

**This worked for me and your 100%:**

1. Modify package.json: "vue": "^2.6.12" to "vue": "2.6.12"
2. Delete the folder node_modules
3. Delete package-lock.json
4. Run npm install

Comment: works flawlessly except without doing first step.

Answer (score 4):

I just had to make these two versions match ( by changing the compiler value match the "vue" value in the package.json and run npm install:

```
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"

npm install
```

No deleting or anything else in this case.

Answer (score 3):

From the accepted answer, instead of deleting *node_modules* folder and run again `yarn install`, you can simply upgrade those 2 packages directly:

```
yarn upgrade vue@^2.0.8
yarn upgrade vue-template-compiler@^2.1.8
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this : `npm install vue-template-compiler@2.0.8 --save-dev`

Converting the `vue-template-compiler` version to same as `vue` version (for this case `2.0.8`) worked for me. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Modify package.json:
   "vue": "^2.5.2" to "vue": "2.5.*"
2. Delete the folder node_modules
3. Delete package-lock.json
4. Run npm install

Comment: mayday mayday maydya... I am still having this issue

Comment: delete package-lock.json @ShahidKarimi I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I used `npm install vue --save` and that worked for me

Comment: worked for me too with a  npm audit fix --force after

Answer (score 2):

As seen in the error message:

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using **vue-loader@>=10.0**, simply **update vue-template-compiler**.
If you are using v**ue-loader@<10.0** or vueify, **re-installing vue-loader/vueify** should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.

I was using a higher vue-loader so I ran the command

```
npm update vue-template-compiler
```

and that worked like charm

Answer (score 2):

NPM have special command to handle such a situation
try this:

```sh
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 2):

Each one of us will have won the solution. So you need to see your vue version from your Error Message. For me, my Error was :
vue@2.6.14
vue-template-compiler@2.7.14

Ok from the Error Message, I find that the vue version is 2.6.14, So we need to update vue-template-compiler to that version, using:

```
npm install vue-template-compiler@2.6.14 --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

1. reinstalling the vue version and the compiler with the same version by example
   npm i vue@2.6.14
   npm i vue-template-compiler@2.6.14

or you can do :
change it in the package.json

"dependencies": {
"vue": "^2.6.14",
},
"devDependencies": {
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
},

or you can do : npm update vue-template-compiler if you are using the latest version of vue,

delete the module file and do npm install

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions listed here worked for me. All I had to do was **REMOVE the CARET** (^) sign from the package versions.

Even thought  my `vue-template-compiler` version was set to `^2.6.14`, the caret caused `npm install` to update its minor version to `2.7.14` and I never knew until I looked at `pcakage-lock.json`. This solution may only work for certain package versions, but it was the problem for me which was simply fixed by this solution.

So I changed the following:

```
"vue": "^2.6.14",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
```

to:

```
"vue": "2.6.14",
"vue-template-compiler": "2.6.14"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete node_modules folder.

`- vue@2.0.8
- vue-template-compiler@2.2.6`

Update the package with a lower version number. In this case, `npm update vue`. 
Optionally, you may want to `npm update vue-loader` too

Answer (score 0):

Doing a clean install helped using the following command:

> npm ci

More detailed documentation about this command can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html).

Answer (score 0):

this command save me.

npm install vue-template-compiler@2.5.16 --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can just run this to change the vue-loader

```
npm install vue-loader@latest --force
```

it works with me

Answer (score 0):

Need to use the same vue-template-compiler as the version of vue been installed.

So I

```
npm uninstall vue-template-compiler --save-dev
```

and reinstall with

```
npm install vue-template-compiler@2.6.14 --save-dev
```

as the version of vue installed in my *package-lock.json* is *2.6.14*.

Answer (score 0):

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.0.8
- vue-template-compiler@2.2.6

Since the version of the Vue-template-compiler is new than that of the Vue

try to match the version

// Following vue@2.0.8 version

> **`npm i vue-template-compiler@2.0.8`**

or

// Following vue-template-compiler@2.2.6 version

> **`npm i vue@2.2.6`**

Answer (score -1):

**[SOLVED!!]**

I went to the very same package.json file of the vue-template-compiler that is complaining, changed the version of the package in there and run yarn, like so:

_~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/vue-jscodeshift-adapter/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/package.json_:

```
OLD:
  "name": "vue-template-compiler",
  "version": "2.6.11"
```

```
NEW:
  "name": "vue-template-compiler",
  "version": "2.6.10"
```

Run:

```
yarn
```

**Source:** https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/10932

Note: path to package.json and versions are specific for my case.