# how to set vue-template-compiler options and where?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

can't understand how to change whitespace options

is it should set in webpack.js?
const compiler = require('vue-template-compiler')

in readme write
compiler.compile(template, [options]) ???

but what is `template` string mean?

I need set whitespace option to 'condense'

Answer (score 2):

Normally you edit `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .loader('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        options.compilerOptions = { whitespace: 'condense' };
        return options;
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to do this in vite