# Vue package Version mismatch

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Am getting a Vue packages version mismatch:Vue packages version mismatch even after updating Vue and vue-template-compiler to the same version The console prints

**Vue packages version mismatch:
- vue@2.6.10
- vue-template-compiler@2.5.16**
I have confirmed from my package.json that both Vue and vue-template-compiler are of the same version .ie 2.6.10  .Please Help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix a "Vue packages version mismatch" error on Laravel Spark v4.0.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397688/how-do-i-fix-a-vue-packages-version-mismatch-error-on-laravel-spark-v4-0-9)

Answer (score 1):

Either run `npm update`, or remove your node_modules + package-lock.json then `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

since you confirming from your question that both versions of vue and vue-template-compiler have the same version numbers, then delete your node_modules folder and package-lock.json then run

`npm install`

will help reinstall packages with the right version specified in your package.json file

Running the following command helped me

`npm install vue-template-compiler@2.5.16 --save-dev`

NB. Replace the version number with the right version that you need. In my case, the version of vue was **2.5.16 and vue-template-compiler was 2.5.13** hence I updated the vue-template-compiler to the version of the vue.

Hope this helps someone

[Vue packages version mismatch error fix](https://anansewaa.com/vue-packages-version-mismatch-error-fix/)