# Vue 3 package version mismatch

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm trying to update a package I made to vue 3, and I'm facing an issue with vue-template-compiler.

I tried to follow a similar post that had some kind of a similar problem but it doesn't seems to work for me.([Vue package Version mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56763599/vue-package-version-mismatch))

I got the following error:

```
> @utt/message-system@1.1.4 build:es
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production rollup --config build/rollup.config.js --format es

[!] Error: 

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@3.1.1 (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\vue\index.js)
- vue-template-compiler@2.6.14 (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\vue-template-compiler\package.json)

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.

Error: 

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@3.1.1 (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\vue\index.js)
- vue-template-compiler@2.6.14 (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\vue-template-compiler\package.json)

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.

    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\vue-template-compiler\index.js:10:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\loadConfigFile.js:516:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@vue\component-compiler\dist\compiler.js:26:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\loadConfigFile.js:516:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

---

Update: I used `rollup-plugin-vue` package, and its not compatable with vue 3, so I installed `rollup-plugin-vue@next` and now I don't get vue-template-compiler inside my `package-lock.json` file.

But now I have a new error on the plugin babel, and I'm trying to resolve this issue, so if anyone can share any ideas it would be much appreciated:

```
[!] (plugin babel) SyntaxError: C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\Components\MessageContainer.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=3d58915e&lang.css: Unexpected token (2:0)

  1 |
> 2 | ._messageList_yig6l_3 {
    | ^
  3 |   position: absolute;
  4 |   display: flex;
  5 |   flex-direction: column;
Components\MessageContainer.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=3d58915e&lang.css (2:0)
SyntaxError: C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\Components\MessageContainer.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=3d58915e&lang.css: Unexpected token (2:0)

  1 |
> 2 | ._messageList_yig6l_3 {
    | ^
  3 |   position: absolute;
  4 |   display: flex;
  5 |   flex-direction: column;
    at Parser._raise (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\error.js:134:45)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\error.js:129:17)
    at Parser.raise (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\error.js:78:17)
    at Parser.unexpected (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\util.js:179:16)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\expression.js:1202:20)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\expression.js:613:23)
    at Parser.parseUpdate (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\expression.js:593:21)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\expression.js:560:23)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\expression.js:364:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@babel\parser\src\parser\expression.js:329:23)

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're using Vue 2 compiler with Vue 3. This is what the error says.

Comment: Thanks for the respond, after I removed the vue-template-compiler from the package.json, there is still the same error.

Comment: Check lock file, it can be seen there where this dependency comes from. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's impossible to answer the question at this point.

Comment: Yeah you were right, I had to check more into this and found out I was using an old version of rollup-plugin-vue so I updated it and now I'll try to find a solution to solve it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

remove "vue-template-compiler" from your app with

```
npm uninstall vue-template-compiler
```

then install compiler-sfc which replaces vue-template-compiler

```
npm i -D @vue/compiler-sfc
```

make sure there is no vue-template-compiler on your package.json and you see vue/compiler-cfs

since you've removed vue-template-compiler then vue-loader will complain to need it to work so upgrade it as well to work for vue 3 with the following command

```
npm install vue-loader@next
```

since you're doing upgrade, there might happen other errors here and there depending on your project configuration. but keeping on solving, soon you'll get it running

Comment: I don't know why, but for some reason I end up with vue-template-compiler in package-lock.json even after running the uninstall command. Any clues? Hm looks like vueify requires it.

Comment: You saved me, I spent a lot of hours trying to solve it.