# How to fix Vue packages version mismatch from vue-loader?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack

I am trying to install the [Vue Filemanager](https://github.com/alexusmai/vue-laravel-file-manager) to my package.json. However, when I try to install the package using `npm install` and `npm run dev` I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/file-manager/FileManager.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js):


Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.6.10 (/var/www/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js)
- vue-template-compiler@2.6.14 (/var/www/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/package.json)

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.
```

I have vue-loader 7.11.2 installed (its a leagacy project). I did not find any instructions how to reinstall vue-loader, but upgrading  vue-template-compiler alone did not work.

I also tried the following solutions:

- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/470#issuecomment-292971628
  Did not work
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43398218/2311074 could not use it, because my versions of vue and vue-template-compiler are higher
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51887838/2311074 same with, versions are too low
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48368175/2311074 did not work
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63777607/2311074 did also not work

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.23.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "2.6.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.10.2",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "bloodhound-js": "^1.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "bootstrap-editable": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap-sweetalert": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap-switch": "^3.4.0",
    "bourbon": "^5.1.0",
    "clipboard": "^1.7.1",
    "codemirror": "^5.49.0",
    "d3": "^4.12.0",
    "daterangepicker": "^2.1.27",
    "dropzone": "^5.5.1",
    "echarts": "^3.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "flag-icon-css": "^2.9.0",
    "flat-social-icons": "0.0.1",
    "flipclock": "^0.8.2",
    "formatter": "^0.4.1",
    "google-maps": "^3.3.0",
    "intro.js": "^2.9.3",
    "jquery-countdown": "^2.2.0",
    "jquery-locationpicker": "^0.1.12",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jstree": "^3.3.8",
    "ladda": "^1.0.5",
    "laravel-file-manager": "~2.5.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nodejs-latest": "^1.1.0",
    "orgchart": "^2.1.7",
    "page-scroll-to-id": "^1.6.3",
    "parsleyjs": "^2.9.1",
    "plyr": "~3.6.5",
    "pnotify": "^3.2.1",
    "print-this": "^1.15.1",
    "sharer.js": "^0.3.8",
    "spin": "0.0.1",
    "summernote": "^0.8.12",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^8.18.1",
    "switchery": "0.0.2",
    "typeahead": "^0.2.2",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2",
    "webui-popover": "^1.2.18",
    "wowjs": "^1.1.3",
    "x-editable": "^1.5.1"
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: how did you fixed it?

Comment: @FAZALHAKIM I changed the version so that they match in package.json, removed nodes folder and reinstalled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vue` and `vue-template-compiler` must have the **same** version number. This also cost me some nerves once.

Comment: clear it has to be the same version but how do you update it